# Mysql filed keyword in Rails model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Now I have a controller:

```
class CommonController < ApplicationController
  def location
    @locations=Location.select(:key)
    render json: @locations
  end
end
```

My database is `mysql`,and `key` is mysql keyword.

But my table juest has a filed named `key`

And when I run the action.I got the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key FROM `locations`' at line 1: SELECT key FROM `locations`
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.just write like this:

```
@locations=Location.select('`key`')
```

Comment: Could you explain why and/or add a link to relevant documentation?